# EMAIL_ADDRESS_BOUNCED, The target object email address is currently marked as bounced.: [targetObjectId, 003O000000u1JvaIAE]

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

In my Visual Force Page,On Click of button I am sending an Email to the respective contact through apex(Using Messaging.SendEmail Method).So If the email address is not proper then I am getting this error I understood that thing.

Can we handle the error through apex and show in visual force page with some proper error message.Is it possible to show?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Messaging.sendEmail has an optional second parameter for allOrNone, which allows partial failures. In this mode, you can read the [SendEmailResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_sendemailresult.htm) responses to render errors.

That basically looks like this:

```
SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages, false);
for(SendEmailResult result: results) {
    if(!result.isSuccess()) {
        // render the error somehow
    }
}
```

Comment: presumably `try { ..} catch (EmailException e) {// display error}` works too although your solution is better as it handles lists of messages